# Can I use only "that supposed to be" as a complete answer?

Tags: phrase-usage

Can I use only "that supposed to be" as a complete answer?
What does this mean?

I want to replace it with the line: this is what going to happen/ this was expected/ nothing surprising/ it's ususal

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Please add details to your question. It's difficult to infer/deduce what you are trying to 'ask'. We cannot answer if we do not know how you came up with the question. Thanks!

Comment: V.V. wants to know the question which "that supposed to be" should answer.

Comment: The direct answer to the title question is "no". Without context, I also don't know what it's supposed to mean or what it should be corrected to.

Comment: edited.........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common response to certain kinds of questions is "it's supposed to be".

> Q: Is the mail here yet?
>
> A: It's supposed to be.

The answerer hasn't checked for themselves that the mail has arrived, but has some knowledge of postal regulations or the habits of their mail carrier that allows them to answer that the mail should have arrived already.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase

> That supposed to be

is 1) grammatically incorrect; and 2) not complete.  Grammatically, the phrase should be

> That **is** supposed to be
>   That'**s** supposed to be

However, even wth the correction the phrase is still incomplete

> It is supposed to be ***what***?

It is possible that the speaker may be trying to say

> That is **what** it is supposed to be
>   That is **the way** it's supposed to be

meaning "*it* is correct that way it is".